# Manually get a CSRF token when testing

Tags: django

I've got a test where I'm checking some authentication behavior.  In this test I need to explicitly check CSRF behavior, so I'm using a test client `enforce_csrf_checks` set to `True`:

```
self.csrf_client = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
```

My question is, what's the simplest way for me to manually get a CSRF token to send with a POST request I'm going to make to that client?

Is the best option to define a custom test view that returns `csrf(request)`, make a request to that view, extract the CSRF token and then use it in the POST request, or is there some easier way I can get a CSRF token to use?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am having a similar issue getting to the csrf token for the purpose of setting the csrftoken cookie for a selenium test.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across this while searching for a solution and now I wanted to share my solution in case anyone else has a problem with this.

The CSRF token is indeed stored in the cookie after you login and to access it I had to do the following:

```
self.client = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')
self.client.get("/url_to_the_form/")
csrf_token = self.client.cookies['csrftoken'].value
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSRF token should be getting sent to the client as a cookie (named `"csrftoken"`). The client is expected to send that cookie back with further requests. Could your `Client` copy the cookie to where you need it?

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but doesn't quite answer the question really.  I was more looking for if there were any ways I could generate the token automagically, without having to touch a view, perhaps using something like `django.middleware.csrf.get_token()`.

Comment: There's not really enough information for me to help further. This is probably because I don't have a complete understanding of your unit-testing framework, and thus I can't infer the missing details about how your testing works and what the tester can access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nine years late to the party, but I stumbled upon this question when I was trying to figure out how to test a `login` API endpoint using Django Rest Framework for which I enabled CSRF protection. Hopefully this helps anyone else in a similar spot.

The solution I arrived at was creating a `csrf-token` endpoint:

```py
# csrf_token.py

from django.middleware import csrf
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CsrfTokenView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        csrf_token = csrf.get_token(request)

        return Response(
            data={'csrf_token': csrf_token},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

```py
# set up for test class for login endpoint

def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    csrf_response = self.client.get(reverse('csrf-token'))
    self.csrf_token = csrf_response.data['csrf_token']
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN=self.csrf_token)
```

Adding the `self.client.credentials` piece ensures the subsequent tests against the login endpoint with CSRF checks enforced pass as expected.